# Integrating two ODE's in MATLAB

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I'm trying to integrate these two equations:

$$\frac{d}{da}(\rho a^3) = -3w\rho a^2$$

$$((\frac{da}{dt})/a)^2 + k/a^2 = \frac{8\pi G\rho}{3}$$

where $a==a(t)$, $\rho==\rho(a)$, $w=w(\rho)$.

For now, I am taking $w$ to be a constant - later I would like to express $w$ as a function of $\rho$. I found out $$\frac{d\rho}{dt} = \frac{d\rho}{da} \frac{da}{dt}$$ to get 'ode1' and expressed $\rho$ as a function of time $t$ instead. 'ode2' is just the second equation. So, my variable of integration is $t$.

Code:

---

```
syms  a(t) rho(t) w(rho)

G=1;
w=1/3;
k=0;

ode1 = diff(rho) == -3*rho*(w+1)*sqrt(8*pi*G/3*rho);
ode2 = (diff(a)/a)^2 + k/a^2 == 8*pi*G/3*rho;

odes = [ode1;ode2];
Sol = dsolve(odes)
aSol(t) = Sol.a;
rhoSol(t) = Sol.rho
```

---

Output:

```
Sol = 
  struct with fields:
      a: [1×1 sym]
    rho: [1×1 sym]


aSol(t) =
  C5


rhoSol(t) =
  0

K>>
```

This is of course not the solution. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

I am open to numerically integrating these as well

Comment: I wouldn't expect your system to have a symbolic solution, and as such you should use a numerical approach, specifically ode45, unless the equations are stiff in which case ode15.

Comment: The solution matlab found is a solution to your equations, but obviously not the general solution which would have 2 constants.

Comment: The solution for $a(t)$ is a simple power of time, depending on the value of $w$, if $w$ is a constant. If I start varying $w$ over the region of integration, I'm not sure.

Comment: Exactly, for general $w$ there isn't necessary a symbolic solution.